# Meaning of "overall" in "excellent overall sportsman"

Tags: meaning

> The description of what happened at Lake Geneva is given to suggest
>   that Rossy is an **excellent overall sportsman**.

What does it mean that he is an excellent overall sportsman? Can he do many sports well?

Answer (score 1):

**good|excellent overall X** might be paraphrased as "an X who is competent|excels in most or all areas or disciplines that an X engages in".

An *excellent overall athlete* might win the decathlon, whereas a more *focused* athlete, let's say a world-class long-distance runner, might not have the arm and upper-body strength for the javelin or discus.

A good overall X  has optimized skills (or features) in all or most areas, rather than maximizing skills in a few areas to the detriment of others.

> The new _________ is a good overall sedan. It gets decent mileage; the
>   interior is roomy enough for three passengers in the rear seat; the
>    engine is powerful enough to pass on the highway although it will
>   never win a speed race; it has good safety features including canopy air bags and computerized traction control; and the price is affordable for the average car-buyer.